# how to extend to a lot of template along with its view function?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

What i am trying to do is that

my base.html to have a Cart.html that extends to it

while other child html can extend to base.html and have the Cart.html available in the base.html

something like this

Catalogue.html----> base.html with Cart.html

Catagories.html------^

i tried include in base.html,  the form and button did appear

but it doesn't pass the class and function from the Cart.html

```
class CartFormView(generic.ListView, ModelFormMixin):
    template_name = 'Shop/Cart.html'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #bla bla bla

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #bla bla bla
```

tried double extending but it is not allowed in Cart.html

```
{% extends 'Shop/Catalogue.html', 'Shop/Catagories.html' %}
```

## or

```
{% extends 'Shop/Catalogue.html' %}
{% extends 'Shop/Catagories.html' %}
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please be more explicit!

Comment: @nik_m ummm  i want the Cart.html where there are save functions in it to be available in every views, without having to write get context and save function on every views,  so i thought extending a Cart >> (childHTML) >> base.html could work

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a separate HTML file called `cart.html`
2. Inside the `base.html` create a `{% block cart_page %}` and enter inside it this: `{% include 'path/to/cart.html' %}`.
3. Now, each page will have the `cart.html` snippet.

Something like this:

```
<!-- base.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
...

<body>
    {% block cart_page %}
        {% include 'templates/cart.html' %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

Now, if you want some of your HTML template not to include the `cart.html` then inside these template write this:

```
{% block cart_page %}{% endblock %}
```

Of course, if you want to include `cart.html` to any (child) template you should do: `{% extends 'base.html' %}` at the top of each child template.

It is better for the `cart.html` **not** to include a full boilerplate HTML (starting with `<!DOCTYPE html>` etc), since it is considered a snippet. The only file that will have the `<!DOCTYPE html>` etc will be the `base.html` (the core one).

Comment: okay i will try it later and let you know, but will the {% include 'templates/cart.html' %} also carries over the Class, def get and def post, that i wrote on views.py for the cart.html?